# Why do Americans pronounce the word "shorter" differently from the British?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, consonants

While I am learning the American pronunciation, I find that the Americans pronounce the word "shorter" quite differently from the British. Specifically, the "t" sound in the word is pronounced like the "d" sound. Therefore, could somebody help me to explain this? Is there a rule behind this?

Comment: I don't think this is just the word _shorter_; you'll hear this difference in words like [_water_](http://www.forvo.com/word/water/#en) and [_patty_](http://www.forvo.com/word/patty/#en), also, and sometimes on the second "t" in [_potato_](http://www.forvo.com/word/potato/#en), too.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, I do know why the "t" sound in water, patty, and potato are pronounced as "d" sound. It is called "flap t". Nevertheless, the word "shorter" is different from those words above. Therefore, I want to know the rule behind it so the next time I see the similar cases I know how to pronounce them correctly.

Comment: If you already know what "flat t" is, I believe you will find these pages interesting: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhotic_and_non-rhotic_accents, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhoticity_in_English.

Comment: Laziness has absolutely nothing to do with it.

Comment: There’s an excellent (and somewhat advanced) discussion of a similar case [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/199077/why-do-people-often-say-hambag-for-handbag/199142) and a less excellent but perhaps more applicable discussion [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/198586/why-is-the-t-in-nextdoor-neighbour-usually-silent-wheres-the-t-in-postm/200556#200556).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the UK has many different regions, only a few of them where people pronounce the perfect "t". This accent is mainly used by middle-upper class people of the south and most people in the north... until you get to Northumbria, nearly everyone in Scotland and Wales would pronounce the "t" silently and emphasize the "ER". Also there's a place riddled with mis-pronunciations known as Essex, people there will not only skip over the "t" but also make the first "r" sound more like a "w" so the word is vocalized as "SHOW-ur"

The Americans (of all regions) would pronounce both "r" more strongly and turn the "t" into a "d" just like the words: "water", "scooter" "bitter", "mortar", "quarter", "porter" and most* other 2-syllable words that end in "r". The reason I say most is because this is not a rule, rather than a convention to make words flow better for the American accent.

The only times when an American would pronounce a perfect "t" in the middle of a 2-sylable word is when the first syllable is long and/or stressed like the words "laughter", "after", "shifter", "master", "hunter".

The paragraph above however, is subject to region in the US where people in the south make the middle "t" much shorter or turn it into a d and people in the north would pronounce it as a perfect "t"... Again this is just for the sake of flow, once you start pronouncing certain words with your regional accent, it just feels natural to pronounce all words in a manner than makes them flow. This is what gives people the ability to "put on" a totally different accent than their own and make it sound authentic.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer has to do with how the "r" that precedes the consonant "t" is being produced in American English (EDIT: when saying the word *shorter* as distinct from saying the word *carton*).

The American "r" can be produced with lips nearly pursed (imagine a goldfish), and that constricted mouth position causes the "t" to move from unvoiced dental [t] towards voiced dental  [d].

The british "r" is produced with the cheeks tauter and drawn slightly back, and that mouth position is more amenable to an unvoiced dental [t].

Comment: Do ***any*** Americans pronounce the first "r" in *shorter* with lips nearly pursed? I certainly don't; it's almost impossible for me to pronounce that "r" that way. I think we only use the lips-pursing for "r"s that start syllables (or at least ones that come *before* vowels.

Comment: They do in my neck of the woods, Peter (southeastern Pennsylvania). The phenomenon occurs (to a varying degree) throughout the US: the lips *protrude* when the first [r] in *shorter* is pronounced, whereas in England the word can be pronounced with a tight, slightly retracted lower jaw that causes the lips to be tenser.

Comment: Your surname here in SE PA would not sound anywhere close to "Shawr" (not an open vowel) but would be very close to "sure".  We say "droor" when we see "drawer". *drawers* rhymes with *doors* here.

Comment: *Drawers* rhymes with *doors* here, too. And *Shor* isn't *Shawr* here, either. But I don't purse my lips for 'r's after vowels.

Comment: Do you not *protrude* your lips when saying your surname? or the word "shorter"?

Comment: This map shows regional differences with a more open vowel [a], so it isn't strictly germane to this question, but it does shed some light on the subject. http://www.tekstlab.uio.no/cambridge_survey/maps/71

Comment: Definitely for *sure*. Maybe a little bit for *shorter*, but not at all for the word *carter*. And it's not the 'r' that's doing it, it's the vowel.

Comment: The vowel is certainly implicated. But if you live in an area where you do say the [r] in carter, or carton, then the way you say the [r] *will* have an impact on the way you say the [t] in "shorter". Remember the guy who tells them to kill the female raptor in *Jurassic Park*? *Shoot huh!*. He's not from  my neck of the woods :-)  We'd say "Shoot hrrrr!" here.

Comment: I don't *produce* an "r" after a vowel at all - the two "r"s in *shorter* are both entirely unvoiced; this is common in my part of England (the south-east).

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo, [like this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qaKZi6p6sxg)?

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski: That SNL send-up of the TV series greatly distorts the pronunciation for comic purposes; the TV series only approximates the pronunciation of the region and gets an awful lot of it wrong.  In that regional accent, the 'a' in the first syllable of "daughter" should be closer to the "oo" in "fool" (the lips protrude), but with the second syllable of the word, they're correct.

Answer (score 0):

I'll add a little bit to Jonas's answer. Americans, when a *t* is both preceded and followed by either a vowel or a voiced consonant, will tend to voice the *t* as well, thereby turning it into a sort of a *d* sound, especially when speaking quickly. (Note that *er* is a type of vowel sound.) You'll notice that all of the examples that Jonas gives in his second paragraph are words of this type.

The only exception I can think of to this is the word *potato*, which I pronounce *potado*. (When I lived in England as a boy, and used glottal stops to pronounce t's, I said *pota'o*, so there's an analogue there.)

Now, in the case of *nt* we tend to leave out the *t* altogether. So I disagree with Jonas in how I pronounce *hunter*: I tend to pronounce it *hunner*. Also *twenty* becomes *twenny*.

If you want to get further into British English, you might want to look into [*Received Pronunciation* (RP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Received_Pronunciation).